# Adding fields to a Junction Object from one of the Master-Detail relationships

Tags: salesforce

In a Salesforce Junction object can I reference fields from the two Master-Detail relationships in formulas and/or the User Interface or am I going to have to switch to Apex code? I can write the apex, but I try to use the built in tools as much as possible :).

To use the examples from the Trailhead tutorials I have

```
1. A Job Position Object (Project Mananger, Sr Developer, etc).
2. A Posting Website Object (Monster.com, Dice.com, etc).
3. A "Job Posting" Junction Object to link the two.

Let's say I add a field to the Job Position Object called "Close Date" to keep track of the date the position closes. Can I display this field on the layout page of the Job Posting Junction object without using Apex code and/or a custom VisualForce page?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that. You can use a formula field and just reference the relationship name of the object and the field name (so for example something like Job_Position__r.Close_Date__c), or if you prefer you can use the "Insert Field" button when creating the formula which will allow you to select the object/field you want through the UI.